# How does the linking process differ when using Requires vs Requires.private in pkg-config?

Tags: shared-libraries, pkg-config

I'm referring to this [guide to pkg-config](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html#writing) for learning how to write one.

At one place, it mentions the following about the **Requires** and **Requires.private** fields.

> **Requires** and **Requires.private** define other modules needed by the
>   library. It is usually preferred to use the private variant of
>   Requires to avoid exposing unnecessary libraries to the program that
>   is linking with your library. If the program will not be using the
>   symbols of the required library, it should not be linking directly to
>   that library.

I understand the implications, but I don't compltely understand how will the linking process differ in the two cases.
i.e given these two versions of *.pc, how will the linking process work?

bar1.pc:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: bar
Description: The bar library
Version: 2.1.2
Requires.private: foo >= 0.7
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lbar
```

bar2.pc:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: bar
Description: The bar library
Version: 2.1.2
Requires: foo >= 0.7
Cflags: -I${includedir}
Libs: -L${libdir} -lbar
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For dynamic linking, all `Requires` libraries will become dependencies of the *program* (the app/lib linking against your lib). If you use `Requires.private`, only your lib will link against the dependency, but not the program.

With `Requires`:

```
+----------------+   +----------------+   +---------------+
| program        |-->| your lib       |-->| required lib  |
|                |   +----------------+   |               |
|                |----------------------->|               |
+----------------+                        +---------------+
```

With `Requires.private`:

```
+----------------+   +----------------+   +---------------+
| program        |-->| your lib       |-->| required lib  |
+----------------+   +----------------+   +---------------+
```